# Ubuntu vm install error [ 233.209703] hub 2-2:2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -110)

Tags: vmware

just installed Ubuntu using VM Fusion, all went well but I get 2 errors below, could anyone advise?

```
[ 233.209703] hub 2-2:2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -110)
[ 233.209703] hub 2-2:2:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled
```

cheers for any help.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610142&p=10054218#post10054218):

> Something caught my eye after looking at some of the other threads. In one of them it mentioned something about power. I disconnected the machine, not shutdown -P and reconnected the power cord.
>
> Not only was I able to format with LVM as I was with the 9100 but after the reinstall there are no errant messages about the usb ports but the keyboard works perfectly.
>
> There was also something I hadn't mentioned previously that during the install when prompted for locale it took a couple of minutes before hitting enter selected English, or anything else. This time it took the enter key right away. Who'd have thought power off / power on sequence would have resolved so much.

If you get problems with a Virtual Machine is probable that the problem is a bug in the virtual machine. Try shutting down your system, unplugging and then start again if the VM maps your USB devices to the guest OS.